# Grass GIS and Python Error

Tags: python, grass-gis

I am trying to use Python with Grass GIS.
To get started I try to read in a raster TIFF.

The import of grass.script works fine:

```
import grass.script as g
```

But if I am trying to run a command I get the following error

```
sloperaster = 'slopet.tif'

a = g.run_command('r.in.gdal',
                      input = sloperaster,
                      output = 'test')

>>>'r.in.gdal' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

Any ideas what is causing that and how to resolve it?

I am on Windows 7 (64bit), Python 2.7.5 (32bit), Grass GIS 6.4.3 (32bit)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are three ways to use Python with GRASS GIS:

1) from the Python shell of the GRASS GIS Layer Manager:

[image]

- you don't need to import any GRASS Python module

2) from the Python shell in the GRASS shell

[image]

- you only need to import the grass.script module

3) from outside

[image]

For that,

- some environment variables have to be set before using Python, see "Creating Python scripts that call GRASS functionality from outside" in  [GRASS and Python](http://grasswiki.osgeo.org/wiki/GRASS_and_Python)
- some GRASS variables have to be set in Python (GISBASE, gisdb, location, mapset)

Comment: I use option 3. I did set the environment variables. Also I think in the right way otherwise I wouldn't be able to import `grass.script`. But I didn't set any GRASS variables. Maybe that's why it doesn't work. I look into that. Thanks.